# Regex matching multiple entries

Tags: regex

I'm trying to extract locations from France. Here is a sample:

```
1#Tunisia#TS#TS#34#9#TS;4#Virsac, Aquitaine, France#FR#FR97#45.0333#-0.45#-1477568;4#Gironde, Aquitaine, France#FR#FR97#44.584#-0.089244#-1429418
```

It's basically a city, its region and its country. Hence, I did this:

```
^[2-5]#(.*?)#FR#
```

The result is:

```
Gironde, Aquitaine, France
```

This extracts correctly the city/region/country but it will extract only one of them. Is it possible to extract multiple entries ? The expected result would be:

```
Virsac, Aquitaine, France
Gironde, Aquitaine, France
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building off your current pattern, you need to replace the `^` anchor with a word boundary construct (to make sure the `2`, `3`, `4`, or `5` are matched as standalone numbers) and replace `.*?` with `[^#]*` to disallow matching rightmost occurrence of the trailing delimiter pattern.

That is, you can use

```php
\b[2-5]#([^#]*)#FR#
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/10Xv0X/1). *Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `[2-5]` - a digit from `2` to `5`
- `#` - a `#` char
- `([^#]*)` - Group 1: zero or more chars other than `#`
- `#FR#` - a `#FR#` string.